# erro ao salvar ou atualizar com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
using (var context = new ClassContexto(ClassMaster.conexao()))
{
    using (DbContextTransaction tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        try
        {
            pacienteModel.situacao = 1;
            pacienteModel.confirmado = 0;
            pacienteModel.dt_cadastro = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

            context.Set<PacienteModel>().Add(pacienteModel);
            tran.Commit();
            context.SaveChanges();
            retorno = "200";
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {                               
            if (erro.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToLower().Contains("duplicate"))
            {                                    context.Entry(paciente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                tran.Commit();
                context.SaveChanges();
                retorno = "200";
            }
            else
                retorno = erro.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

o problema é quando é um update, no bloco Try é gerado uma exceção, pois o registro já existe, ok. No bloco catch, deveria atualizar, porem gera a mesma exceção, diz que o registro já existe, esperava que atualizasse normalmente. O que esta errado ai ?

Comment: seu context.SaveChanges(); não deveria esta antes do seu  tran.Commit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não vejo nenhum motivo para você usar o `BeginTransaction`, você esta tentando salva um único objeto se algo de errado acontece com ele então nada sera alterado no banco, não há um motivo para usar o transaction aqui.

Nesse senário eu usaria um código mais simples.

```
public void Alterar(PacienteModel entidade)
{
    using (var context = new ClassContexto(ClassMaster.conexao()))
    {
        if (entidade.ID == 0)
            context.Set<PacienteModel>().Add(entidade);
        else
        {
            context.Set<PacienteModel>().Attach(entidade);  
            context.Entry(entidade).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que antes de realizar a ação você precisa se certificar se se trata de uma inclusão ou atualização. Desta forma você poderá setar o estado da ação da seguinte maneira:

```
    context.Entry(PacienteModel).State = pacienteModel.Id == 0 ? /*ou outra chave que você tenha de referência */
        EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;    
    //e então...
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Aqui uma boa referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você está enfrentando um problema de escopo e eu também não recomendaria você utilizar a estrutura do try/catch para isso... mas isso resolverá o seu problema

```
using (var context = new ClassContexto(ClassMaster.conexao()))
{
      using (DbContextTransaction tran = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
      {
              pacienteModel.situacao = 1;
              pacienteModel.confirmado = 0;
              pacienteModel.dt_cadastro = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");


          try
          {
              context.Set<PacienteModel>().Add(pacienteModel);
              tran.Commit();
              context.SaveChanges();
              retorno = "200";
          }
          catch (Exception erro)
          {                               
              if (erro.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToLower().Contains("duplicate"))
              {                                    
                  context.Entry(paciente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                  tran.Commit();
                  context.SaveChanges();
                  retorno = "200";
              }
              else
                  retorno = erro.Message;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Leandro, o que vc recomendaria?

Comment: Você pode verificar se o não registro já existe ou se seu [id] é 0 e decidir se deve adicioná-lo ao conexto ou apenas atualizar.